# JOIN 2 table based on relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, express

I have these 2 tables, 1 is Questions, and 1 is Answers

I have manage to get the Question based on Quiz_ID, so I get a list of Questions based on Quiz_ID, but now I want to get the answer based on question_ID, too.

I have done it separately, meaning I get question by quiz_ID, and answer by question_ID, but it's 2 separate models, now I want it just in only 1 query or 1 model? Can I do it somehow with JOIN or some other method? I have read it a bit but it seems messy, I still don't know how to operate it yet. But I know I have to do someway to connect the question_ID of the table below to the upper table or opposite.

Because some works on front-end don't work the way I want so I have to join it in backend like this. So when I axios to get the request on front-end, it'll get a bunch of data, and I'll split it on front-end later, because the separate way is failed.

[image]

Here's my code:

```
Question.getQuesAnsListByQuizID = (quiz_ID, result) => {
//-- I'm trying to change the query in here --//
    db.query("SELECT questions.* FROM questions WHERE quiz_ID = ?", [quiz_ID],(err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          result(null, err);
          return;
        }
        console.log({res})
        result(null, res);
      });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simple join use below query. Instead of * use specific column names.

```
SELECT q.*, a.* 
FROM questions q
INNER JOIN Answers a ON q.question_id = a.question_id  
WHERE q.quiz_ID = ?
```

If you need all data from questions for which there is no answer then use LEFT OUTER JOIN instead of inner join.